# MySQL - Display two columns where first col values in table C and second col values not in table C

Tags: mysql

let's say there are two tables: must_have_products and products_buyed
i want to display, for each customer, what products that they already 
bought as `col A` (GROUP_CONCAT) and what products they still needs to buy as `col B` (GROUP_CONCAT)..

```
Table A(must_have_products)
|id_a| name  |
|1a  | TV    |
|2a  | House |
|3a  | Car   |

Table B(People)
|id_b| name  |
|1b  | Mr. A |
|2b  | Mr. B |

Table C
|id_c|id_b|id_a|
|1   |1b  |1a  |
```

expected result:

```
|id_b  | buyed  | left       |
|1b    | 1a     | 2a, 3a     |
|2b    |        | 1a, 2a, 3a |
```

PS: i'm sorry if the title is wrong, i just have no idea what to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

left is a keyword, you can't use it [mysql-left-function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-left-function.php)

here is the solution:

```
select B.id_b, COALESCE(R1.buyer, '') buyer, COALESCE(R2.lft, '') lft
from
B, 
(select B.id_b , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT A2.id_a SEPARATOR ', ') as   buyer
from B
left join A A2
on Exists(select * from C where A2.id_a = C.id_a and C.id_b = B.id_b)
group by B.id_b
) R1,
(
select B.id_b , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT A2.id_a SEPARATOR ', ') as  `left` 
from B 
left join A A2 on  
NOT Exists(select * from C where A2.id_a = C.id_a and C.id_b = B.id_b)
group by B.id_b
) R2
where
B.id_b = R1.id_b and B.id_b = R2.id_b
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f583da/1/0)

Comment: maybe you could show me the demo on SQL Fiddle, just to prove it

Comment: thank you for give me the demo, i think your solution is the correct one, thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it. Getting the items which are bought with a `group_concat` is easy but not bought is not straight forward.

```
select
t2.id_b,
group_concat(t1.id_a) as buyed,
case 
when group_concat(t1.id_a) is null 
then (select group_concat(id_a order by id_a) from tableA) 
else substring_index((select group_concat(id_a order by id_a) from tableA),
concat(group_concat(t1.id_a order by t1.id_a),','),-1)
end as `left`
from tableB t2
left join tableC t3 on t3.id_b = t2.id_b
left join tableA t1 on t1.id_a = t3.id_a
group by t2.id_b
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3ba94/5)**

Comment: yup bought is easy but not 'not bought', that's really hard, thanks for the solution :D

Comment: well after i think there is a problem, that is the order, if buyed col is start from 2a, left col will be 1a, 2a, 3a because it's just substring, could you take a look at that?